# What is the correct way to combine async-for with an if condition to break mid await?

Tags: python, python-3.x, asynchronous, python-asyncio

If I have a coroutine that's consuming items from an async generator what is the "best" way to terminate that loop from an external condition?

Consider this,

```py
while not self.shutdown_event.is_set():
    async with self.external_lib_client as client:
        async for message in client:
            if self.shutdown_event.is_set():
                break
            await self.handle(message)
```

If I set `shutdown_event` it will break out of the while loop, but not until the next `message` has been handled by the `async for` loop. What is the correct way to structure the `async for` iterator such that it can short circuit if a condition has been met between it yielding results?

Is there a standard way to add a `Timeout`?

Comment: Adding an `if` inside the loop body isn't going to help. You're going to need to change the iterator itself, possibly using some sort of timeout wrapper iterator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way would be to move the iteration to an `async def` and use cancelation:

```
async def iterate(client):
    async for message in client:
        # shield() because we want cancelation to cancel retrieval
        # of the next message, not ongoing handling of a message
        await asyncio.shield(self.handle(message))

async with self.external_lib_client as client:
    iter_task = asyncio.create_task(iterate(client))
    shutdown_task = asyncio.create_task(self.shutdown_event.wait())
    await asyncio.wait([iter_task, shutdown_task],
                       return_when=asyncio.FIRST_COMPLETED)
    if iter_task.done():
        # iteration has completed, access result to propagate the
        # exception if one was raised
        iter_task.result()
        shutdown_task.cancel()
    else:
        # shutdown was requested, cancel iteration
        iter_task.cancel()
```

Another way would be to turn `shutdown_event` into a one-shot async stream and use [aiostream](https://aiostream.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html) to monitor both. That way the `for` loop gets an object when the shutdown event is signaled and can break out of the loop without bothering to finish waiting for the next message:

```
# a stream that just yields something (the return value of `wait()`)
# when shutdown_event is set
done_stream = aiostream.stream.just(self.shutdown_event.wait())

async with self.external_lib_client as client, \
        aiostream.stream.merge(done_stream, client).stream() as stream:
    async for message in stream:
        # the merged stream will provide a bogus value (whatever
        # `shutdown_event.wait()` returned) when the event is set,
        # so check that before using `message`:
        if self.shutdown_event.is_set():
            break
        await self.handle(message)
```

Note: since the code in the question is not runnable, the above examples are untested.

Comment: Brilliant! `aiostream` didn't come back in any of my searchings. Thanks

Comment: @blakev Note that the difference between the two options is that in the first one, `__anext__` will be cancelled in case of shutdown event. In the second one it'll just keep running in the background, only to be discarded once it's done. The former might be considered cleaner.

Comment: both solutions worked great, thank you very much!